# Correct paths in Networkx

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

1. I added an edge(i,j) in networkx random directed graph.
2. After that, I check path between two nodes (these nodes were not connected before the edge was added)
3. The path was returned but j is not in that path.

I am confused that if edge has connected the path then why j is not included. I can not think of a reason behind it. I am using following code:

```
# i=1,j=2,a=1,b=6 
G= nx.gnp_random_graph(10,0.1,directed=True)
try:
    l=nx.shortest_path(G,a, b) #ERROR
except:
    G.add_edge(i, j)
    l=nx.shortest_path(G,a, b)
    print l #[1, 0, 6]
```

Comment: Why would you expect the edge from 1 to 2 to be part of the shortest path between 1 and 6?

Comment: As I mentioned that before adding 1-2 there was not path between 1-6

Comment: Need a [mcve].  According to the output you're showing, there was a path from 1 to 6 through 0.

Comment: I have edited the code. I hope its clear now

Comment: Can you produce something that does not rely on a random structure?  When I run this code I either get 1) no output (if there's already a path from a to b), or 2) if there isn't and adding the edge produces a path, it prints out a path that goes through j or 3) it gives an error if the path doesn't exist to begin with and no new path is created.

Comment: `gnp_random_graph` accepts a `seed` parameter to specify the random number generator's state and allow reproducible results. Without this, we cannot assess what you did because we cannot recreate the problem. Your question doesn't provide enough information without `seed`.